# Trigger a click on the second tab using controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Trigger a click on the second tab

```
  <!--HTML-->
  <tab id="tabID" heading="Second Tab">

  ///JS
  $timeout(function(){
    angular.element('#tabID a').trigger('click');
  });
```

How can i trigger tab by using the property data-target="#tab-two"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use this:

```
$timeout(function(){
   angular.element('tab a[data-target="#tab-two"]').trigger('click');
});
```

Here is an example:

```js
$('#myTab a[data-target="#messages"]').click();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<ul class="nav nav-tabs" id="myTab">
  <li class="active"><a data-target="#home" data-toggle="tab">Home</a></li>
  <li><a data-target="#profile" data-toggle="tab">Profile</a></li>
  <li><a data-target="#messages" data-toggle="tab">Messages</a></li>
  <li><a data-target="#settings" data-toggle="tab">Settings</a></li>
</ul>
<div class="tab-content">
    <div class="tab-pane active" id="home">Home</div>
    <div class="tab-pane" id="profile">Profile</div>
    <div class="tab-pane" id="messages">Message</div>
    <div class="tab-pane" id="settings">Settings</div>
</div>
```

Comment: I used it without a timeout but inside ngAfterViewInit(), Thanks

Comment: @RED-ONE, this is angularjs. The equivalent is `$scope.$on('$viewContentLoaded'`